# Which config is better for data persistence (GAE target), GWT + Roo VS GWT + objectify-appengine?

Tags: gwt, persistence, google-cloud-datastore, spring-roo, objectify

I'm in the middle of configuring and choosing my architecture components for my GWT based we application. I have to choose a simple way to persist my data model on the target server which is **Google-App-Engine**.

Contestants:

- **Spring Roo**: I've tried this and integrated it in my project and it's pretty nice. Seem to be simple to use and the java AspectJ ITD seem a very cool tech to assist me in generating and persisting my entities. For now it only works with JPA so, not really exploiting DataStore real potential (RDBMS only :(
- **Objectify**: Not tried this one yet but it seems great to address directly the Google DataStore API. No fuzzle with JDO. I checked sample usage and it looks very nice too.

Does any experienced guy has an opinion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an unpublished Roo add-on which used Twig for GAE persistence. [Twig](http://code.google.com/p/twig-persist/) is fantastic, there is almost no configuration and problems really only arose when I over-configured things. The problem with JPA on GAE is that it is only JPA 1.0 and it the Datanucleus plugin for GAE is sketchy at best.

If I were solely targeting GAE I would be using Twig or Objectify. If your interested I can publish my Twig add-on as Google Code project.

Comment: James, I think a lot of people will be interested in roo Add-on. Actually I was thinking of implementing something similar but decided to search for existing solution first and landed here.

Answer (score 0):

In GAE Development Mode you can only persist object programatically (I've searched in last 3 days for solution how to batch import/sync data from online datastore to local datastore but it's seem there isn't easy solution for java app - at least as I known) but objectify gwt is good solution for you if you still want NoSQL. One vote for Objectify.